# Do you have a stronger machine, a stronger body for me

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have just got this message on Facebook from someone in London. What does it mean?

> God. I have to much inspiration. **Do you have a stronger machine, a
>   stronger body for me**? Will look. **All things may be churn to the mill**.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me... can you give a little more context?

Comment: The meaning is gonna be ***so*** context-dependent it's simply not worth pursuing this one. Besides, even from the disjointed fragments cited here, it looks pretty obvious the writer is careless and/or relatively inarticulate, and very possibly not even a native Anglophone. (The idiomatic standard there is [*all **grist** to the mill*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22all+grist+to+the+mill%22), not ***churn***. Don't bother with this guy.)

Comment: So as I understand he is a bit crasy?

Comment: What does that "I have **to** much inspiration" mean in the first place?

Comment: Your facebook link doesn't show me the context you seem to be talking about, since I'm not friends with the guy.

Comment: I just answered him that my artworks are as food to trigger creativity... Maybe I was misunderstood or rude?  I am not native and I do not know how call things which cause or motivate creativity.

Comment: Do you know this guy personally? Almost looks like [spam poetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_poetry)

Comment: I do not know him personally and what is spam poetry.

Comment: @Vitaly - Click on the link; it explains what _spam poetry_ is.

Answer (score 4):

> God. I have to much inspiration. Do you have a stronger machine, a
>   stronger body for me? Will look. All things may be churn to the mill.

Yikes.  Terrible English.  First of all, it's "I have *too* much inspiration".

The writer is saying he is inspired by God to do things, but his "machine" (which I take it is a metaphoric reference to his physical body) isn't strong enough for the task and he is asking (rhetorically) if God could give him a stronger one.

Then he misuses a cliché.  There is a phrase *[grist for the mill](https://writingexplained.org/idiom-dictionary/grist-for-the-mill)* meaning " useful for a particular purpose", but "grist" (grain intended for grinding) was unfamiliar so he substituted "churn" (cyclic or repetitive activity that achieves nothing), which is simply the wrong word.

Comment: The use of *will look* is also strange. On the heels of asking if *God* has a stronger body for him—he then says *will look*. Does he mean to say *will **you** look*? I surely don't think he means that he'd be able to make use of a body he found for himself somewhere . . .